# Showing different UIs in a single ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently making a ViewController that makes a request to some API, gets data and displays it to the user.

I designed the UI in Storyboard. But when the data is loading I want to display only an activity indicator and only after that to show the UI with ready data. I also want to show a message if the load failed and a button to retry (again, instead of all the UI I have). So basically, I want to have 2 layouts and show one of them depending on the situation.

What I'm thinking about is creating a custom UIView with an activity indicator and a button and adding it dynamically to my view controller and then removing it. And communicate between my vc and custom view using a delegate.

But may be there is a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIActivityView in your ViewController. Add following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var activityView:UIActivityView?
```

Inside your data loading function, add these lines

```
activityView.startAnimating()
```

Once the data is loaded, add the following line:

```
activityView.stopAnimating()
```

This should work!!